# Java Unmarshalling issue (jaxb)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2, jaxb2-basics

Below mentioned are the xml file i want to unmarshal and create java object:

### test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.test.co.uk/mc/host/201602/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <getCustomerDetailsResponse>
      <name>test</name>
      <age>20</age>
      <company>test</company>
      </getCustomerDetailsResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

To read xml file, i am using below code:

### Customer.java

```
package jaxbTest;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "soapenv:Envelope", namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
public class Customer
{
  @XmlElement(name = "name", namespace = "getCustomerDetailsResponse")
  public String name;
  @XmlElement(name = "age", namespace = "getCustomerDetailsResponse")
  public int age;
}
```

Below mentioned is the main file

### JaxbTest.java

```
package jaxbTest;


import java.io.File;  
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.List;  

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;  
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;  
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller; 

public class JaxbTest {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

           JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {jaxbTest.Customer.class});
            Unmarshaller unm = jc.createUnmarshaller();

            // Unmarshal Customer
            File customerXML = new File("src/jaxbTest/test.xml");
            Customer customer = (Customer) unm.unmarshal(customerXML);
            System.out.println(customer.age);
        }

}
```

---

I am new bee in Jaxb. Above mentioned code is throwing error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", local:"Envelope"). Expected elements are <{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}soapenv:Envelope>
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at jaxbTest.JaxbTest.main(JaxbTest.java:23)
```

Can anybody help me on this please ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to remove namespace part from name attribute of your XmlRootElement annotation.